# Activation of PI_SESSIONS and PI_SESSION_ENDS

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein-recommendations

Regarding Einstein Data Extensions, I was able to activate the same through Personalization Builder and some of the the Data Extensions are being populated.

Looking to the following link, https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_pb_integration_with_contact_builder.htm&type=5, it seems that PI_SESSIONS and PI_SESSION_ENDS aren't include on the integration of Personalization Builder with Contact Builder. In fact I have for example the information of the session_id on the Content Views DE but no session information on the PI_SESSIONS and PI_SESSION_ENDS.

Did anyone accomplish to have session information on these Data Extensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These dataextensions won't show data to the customer. They will always show 0 records. Even if you want to have this data and contact support - they won't be able to enable these dataextensions for the customer.

There is no possibility to see records in these dataextensions.

Comment: So it is not possible to know the duration of each session? We just are able to know that a specific Contact visited one specific page?